# Javascript switch greater than / less than operators not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

The following code gets a screen resolution and works - the variable ScreenWidth contains the correct values yet the case greater than ">" and less than "<" do not work and the code always displays the default image. Changing the first case to "case (ScreenWidth = 800):" does indeed work. I have also tried using "switch (TRUE)" which does absolutely nothing at all, not even the default case.

So my question is "Why are the greater than / less than operators not working?"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ScreenWidth;
ScreenWidth = (screen.width);

switch (ScreenWidth)
{
    case (ScreenWidth > 799): 
        ShowImage = ('Big.jpg');
    break;

    case (ScreenWidth < 800):
        ShowImage = ('Small.jpg');
    break;

    default :
        ShowImage = ('Default.jpg');
}

</script>
```

Comment: `switch (true)` should work fine (`"switch (TRUE)` can't work because `TRUE` does not exist in JS, so you get an error. JS is *case-sensitive*). *"Why are the greater than / less than operators not working?"* Because you are comparing a **number** (`ScreenWidth`) against a **boolean** (`ScreenWidth > 799`).

Comment: Woah... you were so quick there that you beat my screens refresh rate lol

Comment: Yes thank you Felix, changing "TRUE" to lowercase "true" does work. I was using uppercase because that is how many of the examples on Stack Overflow have been written.

Comment: @StrayDog It's possible you happened to be looking at some code samples in other languages. C++ and PHP both have many situations where TRUE is the expected way to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are the greater than / less than operators not working?

Because you are comparing a **number** (`ScreenWidth`) against a **boolean** (`ScreenWidth > 799`). `switch` compares the values using *strict comparison* for equality testing, so comparing different data types will always result in `false`.

> Changing the first case to `case (ScreenWidth = 800):` does indeed work.

That's because `=` is an assignment and the result of `ScreenWidth = 800` is `800`, so you are comparing against a number, which is fine.

> I have also tried using "switch (TRUE)" which does absolutely nothing at all, not even the default case.

Well, `TRUE` does not exist in JavaScript. JS is *case-sensitive*. `switch(true)` should work fine.